# Power management Ubuntu 19 not working

Tags: power-management, monitor

I just installed Ubuntu Studio 19 and I've adjusted my power management settings to NEVER switch off or go to sleep but it still blanks my screen.
I double checked my monitor and it's not doing it by itself.
I've rebooted the system but it's still doing it.

It's irritating to have to keep moving the mouse so I can watch video.

Please advise.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19, are you on 19.04? (if so I would install 19.10 or release-upgrade asap as it's nearing it's EOL) or 19.10?  Have you told your xfce4-screensaver not to blank the screen?

Comment: Is `Display Power Management` in the settings enabled? Try to add the `Power Manager Plugin` to your panel and use it to enable the `Presentation Mode`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called `caffeine` that make sure this problem does not occur:

Step 1: Add the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
```

Step 2: Update package list

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 3: Install `caffeine`

```
sudo apt install caffeine
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this to disable screen blanking timeout. It's doing the same thing as setting to "never" so YMMV

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

Also.. if you are using VLC to play your media, there's a setting in the preferences under the video tab, check the disable screensaver option